# Firefox and Chrome button text baseline different

Tags: css

A button in Chrome vs Firefox:

[image][image]

the baseline in Firefox seems slightly higher for the text. Is there way to lower the text? Just adjusting the margins based on browser?

Chrome CSS:

[image]

Firefox CSS:

[image]

Comment: Can you try removing vertical-align?

Comment: don't rely on default font, use your own font to make sure it's the same cross browser

Comment: Same effect with removing vertical-align. And I'm dictating a font, which these have the same right?  Open-Sans

Comment: Temani, you were right. I wasn't loading the font properly. So they were actually using a fallback font. The fonts were different. Fixing this fixed the baseline issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts were different. Though they are the same in CSS, they weren't being loaded properly so one of the browsers was using a fallback while the other wasn't. To help debug this `document.fonts.check` is very useful.

Thanks Temani Afif for the pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use normalize.css. Most differents between browser will gone https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Browsers have different base settings. Probably FF default line-height smallest then chrome. Anyway, Nobody find this different in normal using ;)